# Como criar um setup usando Inno Setup?

Tags: c#

Estou com dificuldade em gerar um setup da minha aplicação feito em c# e Sql-Server 2018, segundo algumas pesquisas, tentei gerar um setup, gerou mas ao testar a mesma, esta gerar erro de conexão.